# Calculating electric potential -- denominator going to zero

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, integration

Calculate the potential inside a uniformly charged solid sphere of radius $R$ and total charge $q$.

**My attempt:**

There are several ways to solve this problem but I'm curious as to whether this particular method is applicable.

[image]

WLOG let the point $P$ lie on the $z$-axis a distance $z$ from the center of the sphere (origin). $z<R$

Consider an infinitesimal volume element whose position vector $\mathbf{r}$  makes an angle $\theta$ with the $z$-axis.

Let $r'$ be the distance between the volume element and $P$. By the cosine rule (as shown in the figure), $$r'=\sqrt{z^2+r^2-2zr\cos\theta}$$

$$\displaystyle dV=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{dQ}{r'}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\rho\ d\tau}{r'}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\rho r^2\sin\theta\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi}{\sqrt{z^2+r^2-2zr\cos\theta}}$$

$$\displaystyle V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^R\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\rho r^2\sin\theta\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi}{\sqrt{z^2+r^2-2zr\cos\theta}}$$

The only problem is that the denominator of the integrand goes to $0$ when $\theta=0$ and $r=z$. How do I circumvent this problem?

Comment: First integrate, then worry about limits

Comment: Notice that the numerator also goes to zero. $0/0$ doesn't necessarily mean infinity.

Comment: Inside the sphere, you probably don't want to integrate all the way to R.

Answer (score 0):

You have a singularity in $(0,0)$. Could you let it out from the problem leading with on integration limits?